# HTML5 Boilerplate or Responsive Design

Tags: responsive-design, 960.gs, html5boilerplate

I'm trying to decide how I want to streamline the design of my portfolio.  Presently I'm using HTML5Boilerplate with 960 Grid System, but others have suggested to use Responsive for better mobile view points.  HTML5Boilerplate does have a few screen/print Media queries and I'm not a fan of fluid widths.  Which adapts better to any viewing environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to shy away from grids, but that is my personal pref.  I use a combination of the following:

1. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/
2. HTML5 Boilerplate
3. SMACSS

A lot of front-end devs are picking up the twitter bootstrap which may be a nice compromise in your case.